# Print columns in csv file starting from last column using Awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have a CSV file containing thousands of records. Each record is comma delimited with 114 columns each.

I need to print 4 columns: 89,90,91,92 but column 87 and 86 are single quoted and might have comma or special characters inside which for my knowledge complicates the use of `awk` to extract such columns.

I thought it might be simpler to use `awk` and extract such columns starting from the end of the record: extracting column 23,24,25,26 starting from the last column of the record where no comma inside last column exists.

Let me know if you can provide any help.

Example of input record:

```
{144361,1,,,,,,,,,,,,'video14.ams01.hls.','http://video14.ams01.hls.ttvnw.net/hls-826494/wolfontwitchtv_16706535008_316775727/mobile/py-index-live.m3u8?token=id=9043516345222409985,bid=16706535008,exp=1443697094,node=video14-1.ams01.hls.justin.tv,nname=video14.ams01,fmt=mobile&sig=af9c82188126e...','AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.12B436 (iPhone; U; CPU OS 8_1_1 like Mac OS X; en_us)’,column89,column90,column91,column92,’ios','iPhone',298209470,1,,,,,,,,,1,,1,,1,}
```

Expected result:
{column89,column90,column91,column92}

Comment: any example of how your line looks like?

Comment: [edit] your question to use the `{}` button to properly format your sample input and provide the expected output given that input. Also make it briefer as we don't need to wade through a line with 100 fields in it to understand the concept and you want to make it as effortless as possible for us to understand your question so more people will invest their time into trying to help you. Also include what you've tried so far - see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **sounds** like all you need is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; d=114-88} {for (i=1;i<=4;i++) printf "%s%s", $(NF-d+i), (i<4?OFS:ORS)}' file
```

but your sample input/output isn't adequate to tell so borrowing @karakfa's sample input to print fields 5 and 6 would be:

```
$ cat badcsv
11,12,13,"14,141,142",15,16,17
21,22,23,24,25,26,27

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; d=7-4} {for (i=1;i<=2;i++) printf "%s%s", $(NF-d+i), (i<2?OFS:ORS)}' badcsv
15,16
25,26
```

Comment: tried your code below but special characters inside fields after column 92 prevent obtaining expected results. Thx

Comment: Thx for your time. To add more details. Below columns of interests: {…,'column87','column88',column89,column90,column91,column92,'column93','column94',,,,,…}. Columns 93 and 94 both single quoted can contains: {".", "_", "-", "space"}. Columns 87 and 88 both single quoted can contains great variety of special characters. Columns 89,90,91,92 are not quoted and can contains spaces inside, ex: {other ssl}. My goal is to get following result: {column89,column90,column91,column92}. Hope it can help.Thx

Comment: There is nothing special about any of the characters you mention, they have zero effect on this problem. You're making this much more difficult than it has to be. Describing the columns is fine but it's much more effective and useful (since it gives us something to test against) if you provide a [mcve]. Simply edit your question to provide an example with, say, 10 fields as I requested in my comment below your question when you first posted it - modify the example @karakfa posted and I used in my answer, show the expected output and the output from my script so we can see whats wrong.

Comment: Last time: edit your question to provide a sample that's, say, 10 columns wide where you want to print, say, columns 7 and 8 but the script I posted fails due to the contents of field 9. Make each column as few characters as possible in length, just enough to reproduce the problem you are having. Keep it simple so it's easy for us to understand and test against.

Comment: ok found the trick. Tested again your code, setting d=114-87 and got the expected result. Thought the special characters where spoiling the result. Thx

Comment: You're welcome. FYI going forward - the 2 words to avoid at all costs in software engineering are "special" and "new". The word "special" is meaningless in software - there are no "special" characters or functions or anything else so it's important to determine the word other than "special" that accurately describes whatever it is you are dealing with, whether it's characters or functions or anything else. Similarly for the word "new" (e.g. "new awk", nawk, which is now 30+ years old and woefully out of date). If you have a function `foo()` to replace, don't name the replacement `newFoo()`!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gawk version > 4.0.0:

```
awk -v  FPAT="([^,]+)|(\'[^\']+\')"  '{print $89,$90,$91,$92}' File
```

Comment: Hi 7171u, here a sample of column 87,comma delimited and delimited also between single quotes:  'http://video14.ams01.hls.ttvnw.net/hls-826494/wolfontwitchtv_16706535008_316775727/mobile/py-index-live.m3u8?token=id=9043516345222409985,bid=16706535008,exp=1443697094,node=video14-1.ams01.hls.justin.tv,nname=video14.ams01,fmt=mobile&sig=af9c82188126e...'  It can also contain any special character. Using your solution I'm not able to obtain requested result

Comment: This solution doesn't allow for empty fields unless you change the first `+` to a `*`. Also, you don't need to escape single quotes in a double-quote-delimited string. You'll probably want to set the output field separator too: `-v FPAT="([^,]*)|('[^']+')" -v OFS=","`.

Answer (score 0):

here is another approach

```
$ rev badcsv | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} {print $2,$3}' | rev
15,16
25,26
```

where

```
$ cat badcsv
11,12,13,"14,141,142",15,16,17
21,22,23,24,25,26,27
```